# How to render React Component as function return

Tags: react-native, function, object, return, components

Im trying to render react native component as function return, without sucesses, here is the code:

```
// In App.js in a new project

import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Linking, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { FacebookSocialButton, GoogleSocialButton } from "react-native-social-buttons";
import { AuthRequest, useAuthRequest } from 'expo-auth-session';


class MainClass extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
    WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
    Stack = createStackNavigator();
    () => App(() => renderRoutes());
  }

  setResponse = (response) => {
    this.setState({response:response}).then(Alert.alert(this.state.response));
  }


  LoginGoogle = () => {
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
      androidClientId: 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      expoClientId: 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    });
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (response?.type === 'success') {
        const { authentication } = response;
        }
    }, [response]);

    return (
      <GoogleSocialButton disabled={!request} onPress={() => {promptAsync().then(() => {const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest({}, {setResponse(response){}})})}} />
    ) 
  }



  LoginScreen = (LoginGoogle) => {
    const nav = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#a2eff5"}}>
        <View style={{flex: 0.15}}></View>
        <View style={{flex: 0.1, backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: 100/2, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
          <Text style={{color: "black"}}>Please, Login using buttons below!</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 0.2}}></View>
        <View style={{alignItems:"center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
          {LoginGoogle()}
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 0.05}}></View>
        <View style={{alignItems:"center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
          <FacebookSocialButton onPress={() => {}} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  

  MainScreen = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderRoutes = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator 
        initialRouteName={"Login"}
        screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

  
}

App = (RenderComponent) => {
  return (
    {RenderComponent}
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is the error im getting:
Objects are not valid as React child (found: object with keys {RenderComponent}) If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Anyone know how this should be done?

Comment: where does `RenderComponent` come from? what does it do?

Comment: also you have components written as class properties... this mix of syntaxes is going to present learning challenges.  I would write your logic inside `App` and remove `MainClass`. if you're going to use hooks here, stick with that style while you're learning

Comment: RenderComponent Comes from renderRoutes function

Comment: well in any case. this is not valid syntax `{RenderComponent}`. you probably want `<>{RenderComponent}</>` at the very least. beyond that it's almost certainly a function so it would be `<RenderComponent />` or `<>{RenderComponent()}</>`

Comment: When i try to <>{RenderComponent()}</> it says that RenderComponent is not a function, its an instance of Object

Comment: maybe it's actually a react component meaning you should try `<RenderComponent />`. oe maybe it's the prerendered component and you should return it directly `return RenderComponent` try all of that

Comment: All it says when i try return RenderComponent is Object is not valid as React child (found object with keys {rootTag, exp}) if you meant to render a collection of children use an array instead. When i try <RenderComponent /> it gives Element type is invalid: expect a string or class/function but got object

Comment: what are the properties on `RenderComponent` maybe you need something inside

Comment: how do i check that?

Comment: console.log? `console.log(RenderComponent)`

Comment: Problem is,  my screen dont render at moment... where should i put this on code so that logs on console

Comment: i've updated post, see what object prints

Answer (score 1):

The commenters are correct, you are trying to use a hook as a class method in a class component, it's not going to work. Additionally, hooks shouldn't return components. You can easily keep all your logic with a bit or rearranging, move the hook out of the class into a hook, then consume it in a functional component.

```
const useLoginGoogle = () => {
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    androidClientId: 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    expoClientId: 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { authentication } = response;
    }
  }, [response]);

  return {promptAsync, disbaled: !request};
};

const LoginGoogle = () => {
  const { promptAsync, disbaled } = useLoginGoogle();
  return (
    <GoogleSocialButton disabled={disbaled} onPress={() => { promptAsync().then(() => { const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest({}, { setResponse(response) { } }) }) }} />
  );
};

// Then wherever you want your button
<LoginGoogle />
```

Comment: you guys missing the point... the problem here is not with google social button... its with stack navigator...